# Webform 4 - More than one conditional hides or shows component - Confusing Is & Isn't Shown?

Tags: 7, webforms, entities

I'm getting the following error: **More than one conditional hides or shows component** -- Once a user selects one option, it should hide other fields not pertaining to the selection. attached screenshot.

not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok it works with this setting it seems. it seems that once u set it to "isn't shown" it will auto hide it by default. which is why its throwing an error as it cant do 2 conditions at once.

[image]